# Error al agregar al carrito

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

El problema que estoy experimentando es que en mi página web tengo un sistema de registro de usuarios que almacena la información en una base de datos. Los usuarios pueden luego comprar productos, que se agregan a un carrito con la cantidad y el precio en otra tabla de la base de datos. Sin embargo, al salir de la página y luego iniciar sesión con la misma cuenta, al intentar agregar otro producto me aparece un error que dice "Usuario no autenticado". En phpMyAdmin, la tabla de usuarios y la tabla de pedidos están relacionadas.

Mandar pedido

````
session_start(); // Iniciar la sesión

if(isset($_SESSION['usuario_id'])) {
    $usuario_id = $_SESSION['usuario_id'];

    $conexion = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'piedrasalumbre');
    if (!$conexion) {
        die("No se pudo conectar a la base de datos: " . mysqli_error());
    }

    $query_verificar_usuario = "SELECT id_usuario FROM usuarios WHERE id_usuario = ?";
    $stmt_verificar_usuario = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $query_verificar_usuario);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt_verificar_usuario, "i", $usuario_id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt_verificar_usuario);
    $resultado_verificar_usuario = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt_verificar_usuario);

    if ($row_verificar_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_verificar_usuario)) {
        // Obtener la cantidad del pedido
        $cantidad_form = $_POST['cantidad'];

        // Obtener el precio del pedido
        $precio_form = $_POST['total_hidden'];

        // Insertar el pedido en la tabla pedidos
        $query_insertar_pedido = "INSERT INTO pedidos (usuario_id, cantidad, precio) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt_insertar_pedido = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $query_insertar_pedido);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt_insertar_pedido, "id", $usuario_id, $cantidad_form, $precio_form);

        if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt_insertar_pedido)) {
            echo "Pedido insertado correctamente.";
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt_insertar_pedido);
        
            $_SESSION['cantidad'] = $cantidad_form;
            $_SESSION['precio'] = $precio_form;
            header("Location: paginaPrincipal.php");
            exit();
        }else {
            echo "Error al insertar el pedido: " . mysqli_error($conexion);
        }
    } else {
        // El usuario no existe, manejar el error apropiadamente
        echo "Usuario no encontrado.";
    }

    mysqli_close($conexion);
} else {
    echo "Usuario no autenticado.";
}
?>```
````